# How to read dash files

Tags: bash, cat

How can I read a dash file from the terminal other than delimiting it with `./`

For example to read a `- file` we can read it by

`cat ./-file_name`

**Q:** Is there an alternative way to achieve the same thing?

Comment: the recommended way is actually to use `./` prefix. It's the most portable (cf the usenet era's Unix FAQ)

Comment: `find . -name "-filename" | xargs cat` will send ./-filename through the pipe. For your (simplified?) case a mistake, but it might help in large directories / scripts.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For commands which get input from stdin, you can use redirection:

```
cat <-file_name
```

Comment: ya this one works :) is so I got 3 ways to read them one by using ./ other by using -- and another by using <, any more ways to do the same thing ??

Answer (score 29):

Use double `--` to mark end of options:

```
cat -- -<FILENAME>
```

Other programs such as `touch`, `rm` or `git checkout` also follow this convention:

```
$ touch -- -file
$ ll
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja ja 0 Mar 10 13:13 -file
$ echo hi! >> -file
$ cat -- -file
hi!
$ rm -- -file
$ echo $?
0
```

**WARNING:** It's good practice to always use `--` after `rm` in scripts. An attacker could place `--rf` file in a directory and `rm *` would take it as run parameters. See this:

```
$ touch A
$ touch B
$ mkdir dir
$ touch dir/C
$ touch -- -rf
$ rm *
$ ll
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja ja 0 Mar 10 13:21 -rf
```

Oops, this is not we meant, we didn't want to remove directories. We should have used `--`:

```
$ touch A
$ touch B
$ mkdir dir
$ touch dir/C
$ touch -- -rf
$ rm -- *
rm: cannot remove `dir': Is a directory
$ ll
total 4.0K
drwxr-xr-x 2 ja ja 4.0K Mar 10 13:22 dir
```

Comment: You can't count on every program implementing `--`: many do but not all.

Comment: Really? I didn't say that *all* programs implement `--`, I said showed some that do.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk so we have only two options to read the file starting with `-` or do we have some more ??, if you know any please can you list some for me ??

Comment: @vidhan: am not aware of any other option.

Comment: @vidhan you can also complicate your life for no reason and do something like `find . -name '-file_name' -exec cat {} \;` but there really isn't much point to it.

Comment: This doesn't work if the file is named `-` and nothing else? This came up  in the wargame: http://overthewire.org/wargames/bandit/bandit2.html

Comment: @ThisClark: Sorry for the late reply but I was on the trip. In the case of files named only `-` I can't think of other way than passing a full path such as `./-`, for example `touch ./-`. The reason is that many programs consider `-` to denote that arguments come from standard input. For example `man touch` says this: `A FILE argument string of - is handled specially and causes touch to change the times of the file associated with standard output.`

Comment: Thank you. This is an odd statement: `to change the times of the file associated with standard input`. How do you interpret that exactly? Does this mean file creation time, update time... ? What and why does time matter in this case? I suppose this warrants a new question here in the community.

Comment: @ThisClark: the part of `man touch` I quoted is preceded by the following: `Update the access and modification times of each FILE to the current time.` - now it's clear what `times` this excerpt refers to. You can see the whole manpage on your `Linux` machine by typing `man touch` in the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatives become weird:

```
dd if=-x 2>/dev/null
```