# grep getting confused by filenames with dashes

Tags: grep, filenames, arguments, options

I'm having a problem where grep gets confused when the directory contains a file starting with dashes.

For example, I have a file named "`------.js`" . When I do something like `grep somestring *` I get the error:

```
grep: unrecognized option '------.js'
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
```

This seems like the kind of question that would be asked all over the internet, but I can't find anything.

I can manually resolve the problem with something like
`find . | while read f; do grep MYSTRING "$f"; done`
but I'm wondering if there's a simpler / more robust solution.

I'm running Arch Linux.

Comment: what is the exact command you used? try `grep 'somestring' -- *` the `--` tells a command that no further options are used

Comment: the `find` version you tried would work because file names would be `./------.js`

Comment: Sundeep - Lol yes, I'm aware, hence me asking for a more robust solution :p

Comment: You can do the `find` (which unlike the glob `*` includes any subdirectories and/or hidden files) more simply as `find . -exec grep somestring +` or you can just do `grep somestring ./*` -- also dupe https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/189251/how-to-read-dash-files and neardupe https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1519/how-do-i-delete-a-file-whose-name-begins-with-hyphen-a-k-a-dash-or-minus

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As an addition to Romeo's answer, note that

```
grep pattern --whatever
```

is required by POSIX to look for *pattern* in the `--whatever` file. That's because no options should be recognised after non-option arguments (here `pattern`).

GNU `grep` in that instance is not POSIX compliant. It can be made compliant by passing the POSIXLY_CORRECT environment variable (with any value) into its environment.

That's the case of most GNU utilities and utilities using a GNU or compatible implementation of `getopt()`/`getopt_long()` to parse command-line arguments.

There are obvious exceptions like `env`, where `env VAR=x grep --version` gets you the version of `grep`, not `env`. Another notable exception is the GNU shell (`bash`) where neither the interpreter nor any of its builtins accept options after non-option arguments. Even its `getopts` cannot parse options the GNU way.

Anyway, POSIXLY_CORRECT won't save you if you do

```
grep -e pattern *.js
```

(there, `pattern` is not a non-option argument, it is passed as an argument to the `-e` option, so more options are allowed after that).

So it's always a good idea to mark the end of options with -- when you can't guarantee that what comes after won't start with a `-` (or `+` with some tools):

```
grep -e pattern -- *.js
grep -- pattern *.js
```

or use:

```
grep -e pattern ./*.js
```

(note  that `grep -- pattern *` won't help you if there's a file called `-`, while `grep pattern ./*` would work. `grep -e "$pattern"` should be used instead of `grep "$pattern"` in case `$pattern` itself may start with `-`).

There was an attempt in the mid-90s to have `bash` be able to tell `getopt()` which arguments (typically the ones resulting from a glob expansion) were not to be treated as options (via a `_<pid>_GNU_nonoption_argv_flags_` environment variable), but that was removed as it was causing more problems than it solved.

Answer (score 7):

You can try the option of grep which tell "end of parameters"

```
grep -- <string> <filename>
```

This will inform grep to ignore next dashes as parameters and thread them as next elements in command line

Comment: That answer in embarrassingly obvious. I feel like a noob.

Answer (score 4):

Just to post a TLDR answer with the other *obvious* fix,

```
grep -e pattern ./*.js
```

This works for commands which don't feature the `--` option; though it is rather broadly supported, not all commands handle it.

(Notice also the `-e` which similarly works to disambiguate a *pattern* which starts with a dash. You can of course also work around that with something like `[-]pattern` but that won't work with `grep -F`; and if the pattern is user-supplied, it's just better not to mess with it.)

After "(almost) always quote your variables," this is probably the second most common gotcha in shell programming - wildcard matches and user-supplied data can and will occasionally contain a leading dash, so you'd better be prepared.

Comment: This is all included in [Stéphane's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/364934/19240) which of course I have upvoted; but I'm hoping this simplified exposition will help guide future visitors to quickly identify the beef in it.

Answer (score 2):

You solution with `find`,

```
find . | while read f; do grep MYSTRING "$f"; done
```

may be improved:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec grep -H "MYSTRING" {} +
```

There is nothing "not robust" about this.

It solves the issues with the dashes in the filename since `find` will invoke `grep` with the filename prepended with the path `./`.

The other two solutions are to separate the options from the filename using `--` on the command line (which will indicate to the command line parsing routine that there are no more options to parse), or to specify the absolute or relative path to the file.

Comment: You'd probably want `-exec grep "MYSTRING" {} +` or otherwise, as only one file is passed to `grep`, `grep` won't print the filename. Even with `+`, `grep` might end-up being called with one argument, so you could use the `-H` option if using GNU `grep`, or use `-exec grep MYSTRING /dev/null {} +`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks! Still early morning here... I meant to use `+`.

Comment: The *robustness* is fine, but using `find` to work around a simple syntax issue is severe overkill, thermonuclear flyswatter style.

Comment: @tripleee I'd agree with that.

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -name '-*' -exec rename 's/[- ]//' {} \;
```

Comment: It seems to be trying to show how to remove the `-` from the start of file names, but it has several issues:  `-name '-*'` may miss filenames not included in the locale's charset (2) it finds files whose *name* starts with with `-` but tries to remove the first `-` or space in the *full path*. So for instance, it would rename `./foo-bar/-baz` to `./foobar/-baz` (3) it removes only one -. So would rename `./--foo` to `./-foo` (4) it calls one rename per file. If your `rename` supports `-d`, you could do `LC_ALL find . -name '-*' -exec rename -d 's/^-+//' {} +` instead which addresses all those.