# grep to find files with string having special characters

Tags: grep

currently to find files with simple strings I use `grep -iRl "text" ./`
I would like to find following string `->text` .

Tried `grep -F -iRl "text" ./`
Escaping `-\>text` does not work. Getting invalid option error.
How to use special characters? Thank you

Comment: `grep -F -iRl -- '->text' .`

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/189251/how-to-read-dash-files/189252

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `grep -e`:

```
grep -F -iRl -e "->text" ./
```

or

```
grep -F -iRl -e -\>text ./
```

Escaping or quoting the `>` tells the *shell* to pass it literally to `grep`. But that doesn't help with *grep* expecting arguments starting with dashes to be options. Explicitly giving the pattern with the `-e` option bypasses that issue.

The man page for GNU grep on my Debian even mentions this:

> `-e PATTERNS`, `--regexp=PATTERNS`
> Use PATTERNS as the patterns.  [...] This option can be used to protect  a   pattern beginning with “-”.

Answer (score 0):

You can use double minus signs to separate options from arguments:

```
grep -iRlF -- '->text' .
```